# Problem on converting from Kotlin synthetics to databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm currently trying to change my app's layout operations from synthetics to databinding.

I've followed the google tutorial and it works for almost every case, but one is a bit hard to resolve and help would be welcomed.

This is where I need some help:

[image: Layout screenshot]

On the gender picking section, I have 3 cards to select a person's gender (man/woman/pregnant). Behind is a value that keeps the selected gender with an Int (0=woman, 1=man) but if I click on the pregnant case, I open a dialog asking for the pregnancy quarter (codes 2, 3 and 4). My problem is that I don't manage to find a correct organisation for this situation

Does anybody have an idea of how they would do it with databinding? I'm using TextViews for the cards but don't hesitate suggesting other solutions.

Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/longTopMargin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_man"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseTopMargin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/baseTopMargin"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_rectangle"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cera_pro_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/baseTopMargin"
        android:text="@string/a_man"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/paragraph_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_woman"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/largeTopMargin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseTopMargin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/baseTopMargin"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_rectangle"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cera_pro_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/baseTopMargin"
        android:text="@string/a_woman"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/paragraph_text_size" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_pregnant"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/largeTopMargin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseTopMargin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/baseTopMargin"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_rectangle"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/baseTopMargin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pregnant_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cera_pro_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/a_woman"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/paragraph_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pregnant_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cera_pro_regular"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/a_woman_pregnant"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorGrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/paragraph_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should put your state in your activity viewmodel or fragment viewmodel. 
After the user make the first choice, save it in the viewmodel.
When you open the DialogFragment you can access the parent viewmodel and update the parent state when the user make the second choice.

Comment: So the Dialog won't be run by databinding if I understand correctly

Comment: This depends on your app.
Everything can run with his own databinding, Fragment & DataBinding <-> Viewmodel, DialogFragment & DataBinding <-> Viewmodel & Fragment Viewmodel